# Инициализация двух массивов std::valarray в std::pair

Tags: c++

```
#include <valarray>


int main()
{
    const int length = 5;
    typedef std::valarray<int> ArrayInt;
    std::pair<ArrayInt, ArrayInt> PairArray;
    PairArray.first = ;
    PairArray.second = ;



    return 0;
}
```

Хочу инициализировать два массива valarray, созданные в std::pair.
Объекты класса valarray можно инициализировать так:
std::valarray my_arr(0, length), что означает инициализацией нулями 5 элементов массива

Но я не могу так сделать через обращения к объектам класса pair
PairArray.first(...)
PairArray.second(...)

Почему?

Comment: Инициализация происходит при вызове конструктора.

Comment: После уже никак, потому что это закрытые члены класса Pair, так?

Comment: В классе pair нет закрытых членов, во всяком случае стандартных. А инициализация происходит в конструкторе по определению. `PairArray.first = ...;` является присваиванием, то бишь вызовом оператора =.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//например
std::pair PairArray{ ArrayInt(length), ArrayInt(length) };
PairArray.first = ArrayInt(4, length); //четверки
/*если хотите нули, то это  значение по умолчанию, потому 
нет необходимости его передавать _ просто  ArrayInt(length)*/
//можете также по разному получать ArrayInt. Например
//списком инициализации
PairArray.second = { 7, 7, 7, 7, 7 }; 
//или генерировать значения функцией
PairArray.second = (PairArray.first).apply([](int k) {return /*something*/; });
```

Или иначе. Главное получить   `std::valarray<int>` или  `std::slice_array<int>` или `std::gslice_array<int>` или  `std::mask_array<int>` или `std::initializer_list<int>`  в правом операнде